# Properties of an Echo Relative to the Original Sound

Tags: waves, acoustics

If we have a sound wave that hits a surface and is observed after it has done so, have its frequency and amplitude changed?

Answer (score 1):

If the reflecting surface is moving (relative to the medium) then the frequency will change due to a double Doppler effect (the surface is first a receiver and then a source of the reflected wave).  The reflecting surface is likely to absorb some energy from the wave, reducing the amplitude of the reflection.